# Swift Protocol of Custom View Always nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have a custom view **CustomSegmentedControl** in my app which have its protocol with changed index function as below,

```
protocol SegmentControllerDelegate:class  {
    func indexChanged(index : Int)
}

class CustomSegmentedControl: UIView {

    weak var delegate  : SegmentControllerDelegate?

    @objc func buttonAction(sender:UIButton) {
        for (buttonIndex, btn) in buttons.enumerated() {
            btn.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
            if btn == sender {
                let selectorPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex)
                selectedIndex = buttonIndex
               //delegate?.changeToIndex(index: buttonIndex)
                if(delegate != nil){
                    delegate?.indexChanged(index: buttonIndex)
                }else{
                    print(buttonIndex)
                }
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.selectorView.frame.origin.x = selectorPosition
                }
                btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
```

I added a view to my ViewController **Mail** and set the class to my custom view and make outlet for it and use the protocol as well like below,

```
import UIKit

class Mail: UIViewController, SegmentControllerDelegate {

    func indexChanged(index: Int) {
        print(index)
        switch index {
        case 0:
            container.bringSubviewToFront(inbox)
            break
            case 1:
            container.bringSubviewToFront(outbox)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }




    @IBOutlet weak var segment: CustomSegmentedControl!{
        didSet{
            segment.setButtonTitles(buttonTitles: ["First","Second"])
            segment.selectorTextColor = .orange
            segment.selectorViewColor = .orange

        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

    var inbox  : UIView!
    var outbox : UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        segment.delegate = self
        inbox = Inbox().view
        outbox = GPS().view
        container.addSubview(inbox)
        container.addSubview(outbox)


    }
```

But the protocol is always nil and the function never be called !?, What Im missing here ?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: You should declare `CustomSegmentedControl.delegate` as `weak`.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Are you **sure** the delegate is nil? Are you stepping through with a debug breakpoint? You have not shown your `setButtonTitles(buttonTitles: [String])` func... is it possible you are adding the buttons to `CustomSegmentedControl` but you forgot to add them to its `buttons` array?

Comment: @DonMag every thing works fine with the CustomSegmentControl titles, buttons are added and shown perfectly on the ViewController only the protocol is not working!

Comment: @AliAdil - I created a project with your code, and just about the bare minimum of additional code to match what you have. Take a look: https://github.com/DonMag/AliAdil

Comment: @DonMag Thanks man for your help its works without changing any thing !!, but now i'm facing another issue the inbox and outbox are UITableViewControllers and they do not show on my containerview

Comment: @AliAdil - did you figure out what was different between your code and mine?